# Display the individual sum of all the data linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am writing a data structure program using c++ .
This is my code to display sum of quiz I and II of all students. But it is only display the sum of the first student.

```
int totalscore(){
    double sum;
    node *pcurrent;
    pcurrent=pfirst;
    while(pcurrent!=NULL)
    {
        sum= (pcurrent->quizI + pcurrent->quizII);


        pcurrent =pcurrent->pnext++;//move  
    }

    cout<<"The  individual sum are " <<sum ;
};

int main() {
    linkedlist apt;
    apt.insert("643431 ", 50, 40);
    apt.insert( "655222",100, 20);
    apt.insert( "655444",70, 30 );
    apt.insert( "651515",10, 30);
    apt.insert(" 644444", 70, 32);
    apt.displaylist();
    apt.totalscore();


    return 0;
}
```

Thank for  helping

Comment: Please fix your indenting. Highlight your code and click the code block button (`{ }`). Just a little effort like this can attract higher quality answers.

Comment: You should step through your code with your debugger. Single step from line to line, and inspect all relevant variables. See how they change with each step through the program. Your program is a beautiful machine, and the numbers dance with and through each other. This is the way it has been and always will be. Observe their dance. Correct the numbers when they fall. Guide them. They are your children and deserve your love.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not moving to the next node correctly.

Change this line

```
pcurrent = pcurrent->pnext++;
```

to

```
pcurrent = pcurrent->pnext;
```

And, for the individual sum of each student in the linked list separately, you have to calculate the sum and print it in the loop for all the nodes in the loop like this:

```
void totalscore() // no return value
{
    node *pcurrent = pfirst;
    while ( pcurrent != NULL )
    {
        double sum = (pcurrent->quizI + pcurrent->quizII);
        cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';

        pcurrent = pcurrent->pnext;
    }
}
```

The method name `totalscore()` with the return type implies that you want to return the sum of all the students' score in the likned list e.g.:

```
double totalscore() // sum is double type so return the same
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    node *pcurrent = pfirst;
    while ( pcurrent != NULL )
    {
        sum += (pcurrent->quizI + pcurrent->quizII);
        pcurrent = pcurrent->pnext;
    }

    cout << "Sum " << sum << '\n';
    return sum; // return the sum when calculated
}
```

If you want to return the individual sum of all the students from the function separately:

1. you can calculate the sum and store it in a container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector); or,
2. add another element `sum` in the node itself and calculate the sum as you store data and use that whenever you need the sum.